# save email in local storage angular-cli

Tags: html, typescript, local-storage, angular-cli

So I use Angular CLI. I'd like to save email in Local storage. My html code:

```
<input type="text" name="email_field" id="email"> 
<input type="submit" value="registration" onclick="save_email()">
```

My type script code:

```
function save_email(){
    let idemail = document.getElementById('email');
    localStorage.setItem('email', this.idemail.value);
}
```

After click button this component close and  nothing put into storage. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always much better to use Angular Forms for this kind of stuff.

**Template**

```
<form #f="ngForm" [ngFormOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}" novalidate>
    <label>
    <span>Email</span>
    <input
      type="email"
      name="email"
      ngModel
      placeholder="Your email">
  </label>
    <label>
    <span>Age</span>
    <input
      type="number"
      name="age"
      ngModel
      placeholder="age">
  </label>
  <button type="submit" (click)="submit(f.value)">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Component**

```
  submit(value){
    console.log(value);
    localStorage.setItem('data',JSON.stringify(value));
  }
```

Working Example of the same [**link**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

More on [**template-driven**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/template) and [**data-driven**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/reactive) forms Angular

Comment: Thank you! So how can I call saved information? let storedEmail = localStorage.getItem('data.email'); doesn't work

Comment: I've sold my problem

Answer (score 0):

First, do not call `onclick` but instead you should use `(click)` in angular.
Second, don't try to fetch data from the dom, instead use `NgModel` binding.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ah8fst

Comment: its`ngModel` not `NgModel`

Comment: Thank you. What about if I should save some more information. I have to just write something like this: public email: string;

  public saveEmail() {
    localStorage.setItem('email', this.email); several times with different variable names or I can create just one function : saveValue(storageValue: string) {
    localStorage.setItem('storageValue', storageValue); But my function will store information only in "storageValue" but I'd like in email, name and etc